# Phonegap navigator.notifications does nothing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Starting to play with phonegap for the android and am not able to get anything in the `navigator.notifications` to work (actually looks like `navigator.<anything>` is not working).  In my JS I have tried

```
navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
navigator.notification.vibrate();
navigator.notification.alert("one", "two", "three");
navigator.notification.beep(1);
```

none of them do anything, the app just continues right on past them like nothing ever happened.  If I `alert(navigator)` I get `[object object]` but `alert(navigator.notification)` gives null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhoneGap for Android supports all three notification methods you mentioned. For me it looks like you try to run them before PhoneGap is ready (so before `navigator.notification` object is initialized). Make sure your code is not executed before PhoneGap notify `deviceready` event. Just for test you can try to run a code like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
   navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
   navigator.notification.alert("Hello");
   navigator.notification.beep(1);   
}, false);
```

Please also notice that in your example there is a mistake in `alert` method invocation. The second parameter is a callback (executed after user press/taps button on alert), so you shouldn't pass a string there.

Comment: `deviceready` was it. Why didn't I see this anywhere in the docs?

Comment: It is described in the [events section](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_events_events.md.html#Events), however I agree that such important information like application skeleton should highlighted more.